# Solr consuming entire Heap suddenly

Tags: solr, lucene, garbage-collection, jvm

We have been hit by a Solr Behavior in production which we are unable to debug. To start with here are the configurations for solr:

**Solr Version: 6.5**, Master with 1 Slave of the same configuration as mentioned below.

**JVM Config:**

```
     -Xms2048m
     -Xmx4096m
     -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled
     -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
     -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50
```

Rest all are default values.

**Solr Config:**

```
    <autoCommit>
      <!-- Auto hard commit in 5 minutes -->
      <maxTime>{solr.autoCommit.maxTime:300000}</maxTime>
      <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
    </autoCommit>
    <autoSoftCommit>
    <!-- Auto soft commit in 15 minutes -->
      <maxTime>{solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:900000}</maxTime>
    </autoSoftCommit>
    </updateHandler>

    <query>
      <maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>
      <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache" size="8192" initialSize="8192" autowarmCount="0" />
      <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache" size="8192" initialSize="4096" autowarmCount="0" />
      <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache" size="12288" initialSize="12288" autowarmCount="0" />
      <cache name="perSegFilter" class="solr.search.LRUCache" size="10" initialSize="0" autowarmCount="10" regenerator="solr.NoOpRegenerator" />
      <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>
      <queryResultWindowSize>20</queryResultWindowSize>
      <queryResultMaxDocsCached>${solr.query.max.docs:40}
      </queryResultMaxDocsCached>
      <useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>
      <maxWarmingSearchers>2</maxWarmingSearchers>
    </query>
```

**The Host (AWS) configurations are:**

```
RAM: 7.65GB
Cores: 4
```

Now, our solr works perfectly fine for hours and sometimes for days but sometimes suddenly memory jumps up and the GC kicks in causing long big pauses with not much to recover.
We are seeing this happening most often when one or multiple segments gets added or deleted post a hard commit. It doesn't matter how many documents got indexed. The images attached shows that just 1 document was indexed, causing an addition of one segment and it all got messed up till we restarted the Solr.

Here are the images from NewRelic and Sematext (Kindly click on the links to view):

[JVM Heap Memory Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dQAy.png)

[1 Document and 1 Segment addition Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N4FC.png)

**Update:** *Here is the JMap output when SOLR last died, we have now increased the JVM memory to xmx of 12GB:*

```
  num     #instances         #bytes  class name
  ----------------------------------------------
  1:      11210921     1076248416  org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50PostingsFormat$IntBlockTermState
  2:      10623486      934866768  [Lorg.apache.lucene.index.TermState;
  3:      15567646      475873992  [B
  4:      10623485      424939400  org.apache.lucene.search.spans.SpanTermQuery$SpanTermWeight
  5:      15508972      372215328  org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef
  6:      15485834      371660016  org.apache.lucene.index.Term
  7:      15477679      371464296  org.apache.lucene.search.spans.SpanTermQuery
  8:      10623486      339951552  org.apache.lucene.index.TermContext
  9:       1516724      150564320  [Ljava.lang.Object;
 10:        724486       50948800  [C
 11:       1528110       36674640  java.util.ArrayList
 12:        849884       27196288  org.apache.lucene.search.spans.SpanNearQuery
 13:        582008       23280320  org.apache.lucene.search.spans.SpanNearQuery$SpanNearWeight
 14:        481601       23116848  org.apache.lucene.document.FieldType
 15:        623073       19938336  org.apache.lucene.document.StoredField
 16:        721649       17319576  java.lang.String
 17:         32729        7329640  [J
 18:         14643        5788376  [F
 19:        137126        4388032  java.util.HashMap$Node
 20:         52990        3391360  java.nio.DirectByteBufferR
 21:        131072        3145728  org.apache.solr.update.VersionBucket
 22:         20535        2891536  [I
 23:         99073        2377752  shaded.javassist.bytecode.Utf8Info
 24:         47788        1911520  java.util.TreeMap$Entry
 25:         34118        1910608  org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInfo
 26:         26511        1696704  org.apache.lucene.store.ByteBufferIndexInput$SingleBufferImpl
 27:         17470        1677120  org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene54.Lucene54DocValuesProducer$NumericEntry
 28:         13762        1526984  java.lang.Class
 29:          7323        1507408  [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;
 30:          2331        1230768  [Lshaded.javassist.bytecode.ConstInfo;
 31:         18929        1211456  com.newrelic.agent.deps.org.objectweb.asm.Label
 32:         25360        1014400  java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
 33:         41388         993312  java.lang.Long
```

The load on Solr is not much - max it goes to 2000 requests per minute. The indexing load can sometimes be in burst but most of the time its pretty low. But as mentioned above sometimes even a single document indexing can put solr into tizzy and sometimes it just works like a charm.

Any pointers on where we are possibly going wrong would be great.

Comment: I am thinking if changing the following parameters: **1. mergeScheduler 2. mergeFactor 3. ramBufferSizeMB** . Also thinking of removing auto-soft commit altogether. But I am not sure if that would help and what values should be kept for these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem before, but later I investigated and found some holes where it suddenly increases the SOLR heap size consumption.

I used to delta update my SOLR on each record update on my DB, it works fine if document size is shorter.

But as going forward my document size increased it the SOLR stopped working 5-8 times a day.
The reason found is that whenever you delta update a record, SOLR updates it immediately but later SOLR have to adjust all the document indexes again, so while adjusting in process if another delta request arrives it will again start a new one and goes on increasing the heap consumption and at a point it stops responding.

I still did not found the correct working solution for this problem but I implemented a workaround for this that is I stopped delta updating of documents and use to re-index the whole core frequently(2-3 times a day)

Comment: Thanks Raj but I am thinking if changing the following parameters: 1. mergeScheduler
2. mergeFactor
3. ramBufferSizeMB But I am not sure if that would help. Also thinking of removing autosoft commit altogether.

Comment: In my configuration
<maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>
Increase above tag size to multiple of 1024 (expected - 10240 will be ok)

Comment: <query>
    <!-- Maximum number of clauses in a boolean query... can affect range
         or wildcard queries that expand to big boolean queries.
         An exception is thrown if exceeded.
    -->
    <maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses> ----> How is this even related?

Comment: @user1213259 ... I know it's an old thread, but I'm having similar memory spike after upgrading to Solr 6.6. I'm in Solr Cloud mode and using a higher memory allocation (30gb Xmx). I've done a whole bunch of tuning around cache utilization, gc, memory, etc. still can't get rid of OOM. Just curious, did you figure out the root cause in your case? Was it due to delta update as you've mentioned? I'll appreciate if you can let me know.

Comment: @Shamik, Yes I figured it out, and found that it is just due to the frequent delta update request comes up while 1 request is in under process.